# Why am I unable to use a lambda expression in razor view when the class is a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, lambda

I want to display data in a TextBox in my view in MVC inside a foreach loop. Why can't I use a lambda expression when I can use a typical variable? Here is what the view looks like.

```
@model SurveyBuilderMVC.ViewModels.NewSurveyViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = Model.Description;
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Description</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Surveys"))
{

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SurveyId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
</div>
```

Below in this foreach loop I can use @Categories.Description without a problem. There are no bugs and the data displays correctly. I want to put these in a TextBoxFor though so that they can be edited. I get an error though when I try and put it in a lambda expression.

The error that comes up is "CS1061: 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Description' and no extension method 'Description' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

In the NewSurveyViewModel class it is defined as public List < Category > Categories {get; set;}

```
<div class="form-group">
    @*@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Categories.Description)*@
    @foreach (var Categories in Model.Categories)
    {
        <ul>@Categories.Description</ul>
        @*<ul>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Categories.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })</ul>*@
    }
</div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.User.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SurveyId)
    @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Categories.CategoryId)*@
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

If it helps, the controller that sends it the data is

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var survey = _context.Surveys.SingleOrDefault(c => c.SurveyId == id);
        var categories = new List<Category>();
        categories = _context.Categories.Where(c => c.SurveyId == id).ToList();

        var viewModel = new NewSurveyViewModel(survey)
        {
            Categories = categories
    };
        return View("SurveyForm", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Each individual category has a description, but a List<Category> doesn't have a description. That's why `Categories.Description` works - but you should rename your `Categories` loop variable as `category`. I don't know MVC nearly well enough to help you further, but you should think about what that `TextBoxFor` and `LabelFor` are meant to do, given that you aren't using the loop variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this you assume that it is object of some class:

```
m => m.Categories.Description
```

But it is `List` of objects.

You can change your `foreach` by `for` and use:

```
m => m.Categories[index].Description
```

Or use `m => Categories.Description` without changing anything else.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: I will in a few minutes. Have to wait 15 minutes after a question is asked.